# Constructor taking std::string_view vs std::string and move

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I have a class which has a `std::string` member, and I want to take the value for this member in one of its constructors.

One approach is to take a parameter of type `std::string` and then use `std::move`:

```cpp
Foo(std::string str) : _str(std::move(str)) {}
```

As far as I understand it, moving a string just copies its internal pointers meaning its basically free, so passing a `const char*` will be as efficient as passing a `const std::string&`.

However in C++17 we got `std::string_view`, with its promise of cheap copies. So the above could be written as:

```cpp
Foo(std::string_view str) : _str(str.begin(), str.end()) {}
```

No need for moves or constructing temporary `std::string`'s, but I think it actually just does effectively the same thing as before.

So is there something I am missing here? Or is it just a matter of style as to whether you use `std::string_view` or `std::string` with move?

Comment: `string_view` should be slightly faster than a raw `char*` as it avoids the need for a `strlen` call

Comment: @AlanBirtles Does constructing a `std::string_view` from `char*` not call `strlen`? If not how does it know the length of the string?

Comment: Since the parameter is a data sink, the first one is more appropriate, in my opinion.  It will be more efficient when called with an rvalue.

Comment: yes it does, I was assuming you were starting from a `std::string` (it doesn't actually say in your question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> No need for moves or constructing temporary std::string's, but I think it actually just does effectively the same thing as before.

That entirely depends on what the user has when they call your constructor. So lets consider your case 1 (`std::string`) and case 2 (`std::string_view`). In both cases, the eventual result is a `std::string`. Also, this analysis will ignore small string optimization.

So here are some options we can look at:

- The user has a string literal.

  - in case 1, there will be a copy into a `std::string` parameter, followed by a move into the `std::string` in the class.
  - In case 2, there will be a copy of a pointer and size, followed by a *copy* of the characters into the `std::string` in the class.

  In both cases, the length of the literal must be computed via `char_traits::length` at some point. If the user uses a UDL (`"some_string"s` or `"some_string"sv`) to compute the argument before passing it, then you can avoid the runtime `char_traits::length` call.

  So in this case, they're basically the same.
- The user has a `std::string` lvalue which they want to keep the value of.

  - In case 1, there will be a copy into the `std::string` parameter, followed by a move into the `std::string` member.
  - In case 2, there will be a copy of a pointer and size into the `std::string_view` parameter, followed by a copy of the characters into the `std::string` in the class

  In both cases, the length is not computed, since `std::string` knows its length. Again, in this case, they're the same.
- The user has a `std::string` value they want to move into the object. So this is either a prvalue or an explicit `std::move`.

  - In case 1, there will be a move-construction of the parameter, followed by the move-construction of the member.
  - In case 2, there will be a copy of a pointer and size, followed by a copy of the *characters* into the `std::string` member.

  See the difference? In case 1, no characters ever get copied; there are only moves. This is because what the user has and what your class *needs* are identical. So you get the most efficient transfer possible.

  In case 2, characters must get copied, because the `string_view` parameter has no idea that the user doesn't want to keep the string around. Therefore, neither does the constructor of the `string` member being invoked.

When you use an intermediary for a transfer where the source and destination types are the same, then you can introduce an inefficiency. If the user has the type you actually intend to use, then it is better performance-wise for your interface to express that type directly. If you use a view intermediary, then information and intent between the caller and the callee can get lost.

`string_view` is a lingua-franca type; it is primarily intended for when you want to use an array of characters without forcing the user to use a specific string type. For a use case where you intend to keep those characters around beyond the function call, a lingua-franca type is is sub-optimal because the *only* thing you can do to preserve them is copy them into your own string.

Unless it is important to keep `std::string` (or whatever string type you use) out of your interface, or if it's impossible for the user to directly pass the type you're storing the characters in (you may be storing an array, for example), you should use it as the parameter type.

But of course, this is all micro-optimization territory. Unless this class is being used a whole bunch, the difference is trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider some scenarios:

```
Foo(std::string s) : str_(std::move(s)) {}
string s1;

Foo("abc");           // A - construct from string literal
Foo (s1);             // B - construct from existing string
Foo (string("def"));  // C - construct from temporary string
```

- In case (A), the compiler creates a temporary string, passes it to `Foo`'s constructor, which moves from it.
- In case (B), the compiler makes a copy of `s1` and passes it to `Foo`'s constructor, which moves from the copy.
- In case (C), the compiler passes the temporary string to `Foo`'s constructor, which moves from it.

If instead, we have:

```
Foo(std::string_view sv) : str_(sv.begin() sv.end()) {}
string s1;

Foo("abc");           // A - construct from string literal
Foo (s1);             // B - construct from existing string
Foo (string("def"));  // C - construct from temporary string
```

- In case (A), the compiler creates a `string_view` (calling `strlen`) and passes that. The character data is copied into `str_`
- In case (B), the compiler creates a `string_view` from `s1.data()` and `s1.size()` and passes that. The character data is copied into `str_`
- In case (C), makes a string view from the temporary string, and passes that. The character data is copied into `str_`

Neither approach is best in all cases.
The first approach works great for (A) and (C), and OK for (B)

The second approach works great for (A), and (B), and not so great for (C).